# Torsion of 3D Point Cloud

Tags: point-cloud

Hi may be my question is not asked at the right forum, So I'm very sorry.
I'm trying to characterize deformations of the Bladder (described by a set of Point clouds), so I'm searching a formula or something to describe torsions (or twists) at each vertex of the point Cloud along all the deformed sequences of the Bladder.
I know how to do it in 2D, but in 3D case I have no idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thanks. I read the "how to ask a good question" but I didn't know what is the problem with my question